# Is there any way to execute the UI tests in headless mode in Selenium version 4 and heigher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Recently Selenium released their major version as Selenium 4 and announced there will not be any support further for PhantomJS from Selenium4 onwards. Is that mean Selenium no longer supports for headless automation or is there any way to execute the tests in headless mode in Selenium version 4? Appreciate code examples.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @cruisepandey Could you please let me know what are the details you are looking for? As my understanding in English there is only one question here. If you know Selenium did release it's next version you will understand the question. still some people can understand the question and even answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Selenium 4, native support has been removed for PhantomJS. Still, the users who run the scripts on headless mode using PhantomJS, can use Chrome or Firefox in headless mode as shown below.

```
const chrome = require('../chrome');
const firefox = require('../firefox');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('..');

const width = 640;
const height = 480;

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(
        new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize({width, height}))
    .setFirefoxOptions(
        new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize({width, height}))
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr')
    .then(_ =>
        driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN))
    .then(_ => driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000))
    .then(
        _ => driver.quit(),
        e => driver.quit().then(() => { throw e; }));
```

To learn more about Selenium 4 changes please refer [Selenium 4 (alpha) is Released: What’s New?](https://medium.com/@4400vijay/selenium-4-alpha-is-released-whats-new-7fce5e8cd926)